# How to use asynchronous function to load page before the function end

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am computing data inside a function that loop over two different json files, but even with the async tag in front of my function if the function did not finish to compute all the data, my front end will still be loading.

So i was wondering, is there a way to do it fully asynchronous ? 
Or is it just not possible in this case ?

What i'v tried so far is :

**JS part**

```
mounted() {
        // Count line inside appsession.json
        this.findMatch()
        },


... Inside Methods :


    async findMatch(){
            var result=[]
        this.loading=true
        var x=0
        var z=0

        console.log('test:',Object.keys(this.session).length)
        var l=Object.keys(this.session).length
        for(var i in this.session)
            {

               this.percentage=((i/l)*100)
                //console.log((i*Object.keys(this.session).length)*100)
                for(var y in this.users)
                {
                    if(this.session[i]._source.deviceID==this.users[y].device_id){
                        result.push(this.session[i]._source.deviceID)
                        if(this.session[i]._source.deviceOS=="ios"){
                            this.ios=this.ios+1
                        }
                        else if(this.session[i]._source.deviceOS=="android"){
                            this.android=this.android+1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        this.InitPieChartMobiles()
        this.loading=false
      },
```

**Front end Part :**

```
loading : {{ percentage }}%
        <template>
        <div v-if="loading">
            <div class="lds-hourglass"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
        </div>
         <div class="small">
            <pie-chart :chart-data="usercollection"></pie-chart>
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <pie-chart :chart-data="mobiles"></pie-chart>
        </div>
        </template>
```

I guess there is some way to do it since i already used components that whould show if a v-if is a true. But i can't point my finger on what to do or how to do it.

Thanks for you time !

Comment: adding `async` before any function doesn't make it run out of main js thread. It just makes the function to return a promise

Comment: what you can do to load the other part of the page is use `setTimeout`. Even this will run on the main thread but it will just run after the call stack is empty i-e will make a deferred execution of your function

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks for your informations

Comment: "if the function did not finish (...), my front end will still be loading". Well yeah, you are setting `this.loading = true` at the very beginning of the method :) I don't understand what's exactly your problem here - as far as I understand you *need* this loading as the data that is visible would depend on the calculations you do?

Comment: I'll delete the loading var, it has nothing to do with the current issue, it is just a boolean var that i use for a loading screen

Comment: are you sure you haven't confused the terms synchronous and asynchronous